# python-pptx access table cell properties and apply it back during replace

Tags: python, automation, formatting, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to replace the table headers in powerpoint using `python-pptx` using the code below

```
slides = [slide for slide in ip_ppt.slides]
shapes = []
for slide in slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        shapes.append(shape)

def replace_text(replacements:dict,shapes:list):
            if shape.has_table:
                for row in shape.table.rows:
                    for cell in row.cells:
                        if match in cell.text:
                            new_text = cell.text.replace(str(match), str(replacement))
                            cell.text = new_text


replace_text({'FY2122':'FY22/23'},shapes)
replace_text({'FY2021':'FY21/22'},shapes)
replace_text({'FY1920':'FY20/21'},shapes)
```

While this does the replacement successfully, but the terms after replacement lose the formatting such as font size, font color and alignment. example like below

[image]

When I press `cell.f` tab,it only populates `for` and `find`. When I press `cell.c` tab, it only populates `curr_text`, `cell`, `cells`. I was expecting to see `color` but it doesn't show up.

So, I tried the below but they returned `None`

```
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    print(paragraph.font.size)
                    print(paragraph.font.color)
                    print(paragraph.font.alignment)
```

Along with value replacement, I would also like to explicitly code in my for loop to assign/copy the same format (such as font size, font color etc) to my replacement term as well.

I would like to extract the properties of cell (font color, font size etc) in a table and assign it back to same cell (after replacement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of others. I drilled down to run level to extract the font properties like name, size and reassigned it back to my replacement text. This solved the problem for me

```
   if shape.has_table:
        for row in shape.table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                paras = cell.text_frame.paragraphs
                for para in paras:
                    #print(para.text)
                    for run in para.runs:
                        if match in run.text:
                            new_text = run.text.replace(str(match), str(replacement))
                            fn = run.font.name
                            fz = run.font.size 
                            run.text = new_text
                            run.font.name = fn
                            run.font.size = fz
```

Answer (score 0):

download pptx-tables on my repo: https://github.com/bharath5673/python-pptx-tables

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx_tables import PptxTable

prs=Presentation()
prs.slide_width = Inches(13.333)
prs.slide_height = Inches(7.5)


data = [
        [['Aa', 'Bb','Cc'],
        [3,     4,      5],
        [6,     7,      8]],

        [['Dd', 'Ee','Ff'],
        [0,     1,      2],
        [6,     7,      8]]
        ]



for n,lst in enumerate(data):

    lyt=prs.slide_layouts[6] # choosing a slide layout
    slide=prs.slides.add_slide(lyt) # adding a slide
    # title=slide.shapes.title 
    title_name = f"Page : "+str(n)
    # title.text=title_name
    # subtitle=slide.placeholders[1]


    tbl = PptxTable(lst,prs)
    tbl.set_table_location(left=Inches(1.5), top=Inches(2), width=Inches(5))
    # tbl.set_formatting(font_size=Pt(7), row_height=Inches(.3),alignment=PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.LEFT)
    tbl.set_formatting(font_size=Pt(12), row_height=Inches(.85))        
    tbl.create_table(slide_index=n,
                      columns_widths_weight=[2, 2, 2],
                      transpose=True,
                      )


tbl.save_pptx("slide_table.pptx")
```

demo
[image]